# Yii2 запросы к бд

Tags: mysql, sql, yii2, запрос

Добрый день. Подскажите пожалуйста как составить запрос что бы считалась сумма указанных полей? Я вот так делаю

```
$sum = (new Query())->select('count')->sum('count')->from('vote')->where(['poll_id' => $id]);
```

Появляется ошибка

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'count' in 'field list'
```

The SQL being executed was: SELECT SUM(count)

Причем если выполнить такой запрос

```
SELECT SUM(count) FROM vote WHERE poll_id=$id
```

в phpmyadmin, то сумма считается.

Если же делать запрос без конструктора, а через 
`$sum = Yii::$app->db->createCommand("SELECT SUM(count) FROM vote WHERE poll_id=$id")`
 и сделать vat_dump($sum), то вернет NULL. При этом ошибок никаких нет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$rows = (new Query())->from('vote')->where(['poll_id' => $id])->sum('count');
```